# R rmongodb try() not catching error potentially caused by bad data

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch, rmongodb

I am using R and rmongodb to extract data from a MongoDB NoSQL database. I put in `try()` logic to catch problems arise from bad data.  Most of the time, `try()` would catch the error and skip the bad data object.  Once in a while though, it "fails" to catch it and my program halts.  Below is the code that sometimes work but fails to get into the `if(inherits(...))` once in a while.  I put in checks to make sure `iter1` is valid (as much as I know) before calling the `mongo.son.iterator.value()` function. In fact, I used `try()` on calls like the below in the entire program.  I had tried `tryCatch` before but I think the result was the same.  Any help is much appreciated!

```
v2 <- try(mongo.bson.iterator.value(iter1)) 

if(inherits(v2, "try-error")) {
    cat("mongo.bson.iterator.VALUE(iter1) ERROR ^^^^^^ , next!")
    Sys.sleep(10)
    next;
}
```

Output:

```
ItemName =  VH013269
before value(iter1)
 type of iter1:  integer
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7402cd5, cause 'memory not mapped'
Traceback:
 1: .Call(".mongo.bson.iterator.value", iter)
 2: mongo.bson.iterator.value(iter1)
 3: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 4: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 5: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 6: tryCatch(expr, error = function (e) {
        call <- conditionCall(e)
        if (!is.null(call)) {
            if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch))) 
                call <- sys.call(-4L)
            dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]
            prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")
            LONG <- 75L
            msg <- conditionMessage(e)
            sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]
            w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")
            if (is.na(w)) 
                w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "b")
            if (w > LONG) 
                prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")
        }
        else prefix <- "Error : "
        msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")
        .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))
        if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"), 
            TRUE)) {
            cat(msg, file = stderr())
            .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())
        }
        invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))
    })
 7: try(mongo.bson.iterator.value(iter1))
 8: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
 9: eval(ei, envir)
10: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
11: source("parcc_mci_v5.R")
Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

Answer (score 1):

`try` can only catch errors at the R level. The segfault you see is because the `.mongo.bson.iterator.value` C/C++ function is accessing memory it shouldn't be.

You should report this to the package maintainer, with a reproducible example, if possible.

Comment: Thanks, Joshua! Your answer confirmed my suspicion.  Is there a way for R to handle the C/C++ memory issue?  I am pretty much stuck.  I should contact the maintainer of Rmongodb, and not the authors, correct?

Comment: @S.Lowe: Yes, you should report this to the package maintainer, with a reproducible example, if possible.